# How to use if_else and mutate to substitute the value in charactor vector as condition?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to generate one column in data with previous value if the condition in if_else are/aren`t consistent with, the value will be the same as the original column.

Here is the code:

```r
iristest <- iris
iristest %>% mutate(Species=if_else(Species=='setosa','Setosa',Species))
```

Here is the error:

```
#Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Species`.
#i `Species = if_else(Species == "setosa", "Setosa", Species)`.
#x `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object.
```

How do I solve the problem? I know it can be solved with a char function such as `stringr`, but I hope and think it could be solved in a `mutate` way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following -

```
library(dplyr)

iristest %>% mutate(Species = factor(if_else(Species=='setosa',
                              'Setosa',as.character(Species))))
```

Since, `Species` is of type `factor` you can use factor specific functions to recode the value. Here, we can use `fct_recode` from `forcats`.

```
iristest %>% mutate(Species= forcats::fct_recode(Species, Setosa = 'setosa'))
```

Comment: That is what I need, and so glad to learn the `fct_recode`.Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can just set the `levels`

```
levels(iristest$Species)[levels(iristest$Species) == 'setosa'] <- "Setosa"
```

Comment: Oh, it`s a simple way to understand, thanks!